# Append text at the beginning of lines that match the regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have this file with text:

```
#EXTINF:9.843,
247.ts
#EXTINF:9.844,
248.ts
#EXTINF:9.843,
249.ts
#EXTINF:9.843,
250.ts
#EXTINF:9.844,
```

I need to append some text at the beginning of each x.ts line

I tried to use Notepad++, find and replace using regex, but I couldn't make that work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assert the start of the line `^`, then capturing in a group one or more digits followed by a dot and ts `(\d+\.ts)` and assert the end of the line `$`

[`^(\d+\.ts)$`](https://regex101.com/r/MMuCHF/1)

In the replacement start with what you want to append followed by group 1:

`text$1`.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you can try the command line `cc.abl <yourText> <lineFilter>` of [ConyEdit](https://www.conyedit.com/)(a plugin).
For Example, with ConyEdit running in the background, copy the text and the command line below:

```
#EXTINF:9.843,
247.ts
#EXTINF:9.844,
248.ts
#EXTINF:9.843,
249.ts
#EXTINF:9.843,
250.ts
#EXTINF:9.844,
cc.abl 'your text '  /\d+\.ts/
```